# R - converting a list into a data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list that consists of lists that all contain four elements. It looks like this:

```
> summary(allMorans)
                      Length Class  Mode
trait1                 4      -none- list
trait2                 4      -none- list
trait3                 4      -none- list
traitB                 4      -none- list
traitX                 4      -none- list
```

The four elements are the result of a certain statistical test and contain the elements "observed", "expected", "sd", "pvalue".

If I do this:

```
MoransResults <- as.data.frame(allMorans)
```

I get a single very long row that looks like this:

```
 trait1.observed    trait1.expected    trait1.sd      trait1.pvalue       trait2.observed    trait2.expected   trait2.sd      trait2.pvalue    ...etc  
 0.1                0.2                0.01           0.09                0.3                0.2               0.01           0.07             ...etc
```

However, I need to turn this list of lists into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
TRAIT    observed   expected   sd     pvalue
trait1   0.1        0.2        0.01   0.09
trait2   0.3        0.2        0.01   0.07
trait3   0.1        0.1        0.01   0.55
traitB   0.2        0.2        0.01   0.49
traitX   0.3        0.2        0.01   0.07
```

How do I achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

As requested in the comments, here is some example data:

```
> dput(allMorans)
structure(list(trait1 = structure(list(observed = -0.00820649454281412, 
expected = -0.0001000100010001, sd = 6.44860382275647e-05, 
p.value = 0), .Names = c("observed", "expected", "sd", "p.value"
)), trait2 = structure(list(observed = -0.16378930443073, expected = -0.0001000100010001, 
sd = 6.44860728086603e-05, p.value = 0), .Names = c("observed", 
"expected", "sd", "p.value")), trait3 = structure(list(observed = -0.348047732487769, 
expected = -0.0001000100010001, sd = 6.44872069930741e-05, 
p.value = 0), .Names = c("observed", "expected", "sd", "p.value"
))), .Names = c("trait1", "trait2", "trait3"))
```

Comment: It's not really enough to just describe what your data are like.  You need to include actual example data in the question (e.g. `dput(allMorans)`)

Comment: Ok thanks, I will add that to the question! -edit- done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R (no additional libraries necessary)

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(allMorans, as.data.frame))
#           observed    expected           sd p.value
#trait1 -0.008206495 -0.00010001 6.448604e-05       0
#trait2 -0.163789304 -0.00010001 6.448607e-05       0
#trait3 -0.348047732 -0.00010001 6.448721e-05       0
```

Comment: instead of `lapply` you can just use `sapply`  and the identity function as   `t(sapply(allMorans,I))` though the best is to use s`simplify2array` which is still in base R

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative:

```
t(simplify2array(allMorans))

#           observed     expected             sd   p.value
#trait1 -0.008206495  -0.00010001   6.448604e-05      0      
#trait2 -0.1637893    -0.00010001   6.448607e-05      0      
#trait3 -0.3480477    -0.00010001   6.448721e-05      0
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `tidyverse` package. `as.tibble` convert each element in the list to be a `tibble`. `map_dfr` can then combine all these tibbles
 to form the final output.

```
library(tidyverse)

dt <- allMorans %>% map_dfr(as.tibble, .id = "TRAIT")
dt
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#    TRAIT     observed    expected           sd p.value
#    <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 trait1 -0.008206495 -0.00010001 6.448604e-05       0
# 2 trait2 -0.163789304 -0.00010001 6.448607e-05       0
# 3 trait3 -0.348047732 -0.00010001 6.448721e-05       0
```